# Numerical analysis / Linear algebra resource to practice problems

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, numerical-linear-algebra, book-recommendation, online-resources

I am studying for a college course on numerical analysis. The current module is numerical solutions to linear equations. I am looking for resources that have lots of practice problems. I have already studied the theory and just want to practice different questions. The topics I wish to emphasise on:

- matrix norms
- spectral radius
- singular values
- iterated powers of matrices
- condition numbers
- iterative methods

(and any related topics). I don't mind if the resources are books or online references. I just want many difficult questions to practice

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too late to help the original poster to help with their course, but it may be useful to others.

There are [several](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971446?mobileUi=0) [great](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/GVL4/golubandvanloan.htm) [books](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/text.html) [on](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319050881) numerical linear algebra, all of which have good exercises on most or all of the topics you mention. If you're looking for exercises in particular, a recent book deserves particular mention.

The book [*Numerical Linear Algebra and Matrix Factorizations*](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030364670) by Lyche has a number of exercises at a variety of difficulty levels. Further, worked solutions appear in a companion book [*Exercises in Numerical Linear Algebra and Matrix Factorizations*](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030597887) by Lyche, Muntingh, and Ryan. I don't have deep experience using these resources, but the problems seem like a good mix, and worked solutions are always helpful when self-studying (though one must resist temptation to not run to the solution manual too soon!). Both books are available on [SpringerLink](https://link.springer.com) and thus might be available for free to you if your university has an institutional subscription.